# javac : Compiling a .java file which uses other classes in it

Tags: java, compiler-errors

HI i have 3 java files

```
a.java  
b.java  
c.java
```

I managed to generate .class files for both a and b using

```
javac example/a.java  
javac example/b.java
```

but when i do the same for c.java I get the error
error: cannot find symbol b and c

Any suggestions on how i could solve this problem ?

All the java files are in the same folder

Comment: do you want to show us the code of c.java?

Comment: Actually a and b were suppositions and c is actually Order.java Here is the code Customer,Address,Shipping and Item are the other objects which compiled without any trouble. Since i couldnt paste the code here i posted the code at [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/580168/java/java/javac-Compiling-JAVA-file-which#2638811)

Comment: Related link: [How the Java Launcher Finds User Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html#userclass).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to have classes `a` and `b` in your classpath when you try to compile class `c`.  This allows the compiler to verify that they exist, figure out what methods they have, etc.

`javac` is pretty sensitive to package names and classpaths.  The easiest thing to do is to compile all three at the same time like so `javac example/a.java example/b.java example/c.java`.

If you go to the parent directory of example (let's call it `src`), then you can run the following:

```
javac -cp src src/example/c.java
```

The reason you have to do it this way is because your classes have their packages listed as `example`.  Because of your package name, `javac` is looking for the `example` directory in its classpath, where it expects to find `a.class` and `b.class`.

Comment: java -cp example c.java (Invalid syntax and path)

Comment: javac example/a.java example/b.java example/c.java or javac *.java worked

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're not in the `example/` directory when you run `javac`.  Try

```
javac -cp example c.java
```

Or just `cd` into that directory.  The classpath is not automatically resolved for the classes `c.java` *depends* on.

Comment: If his package is example that may make a problem

Comment: @Amir Afghani Have a look at the last post at [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/580168/java/java/javac-Compiling-JAVA-file-which#2638812)