# Using Class Objects : Class is user defined : Java

Tags: java

I have made a class named Log in a file named Log.java.

Now, I am trying to instantiate an Object of class Log in another Class (lets say Trace.java), in main method (public static void main(String argv[])).

Whenever I try to execute follwing snippet, I get an error

```
Log l = new Log();
```

Error is :

```
error: cannot find symbol
    Log l = new Log();
    ^
```

Comment: Is `Log` in the same package? If not, you need to import it.

Comment: You're not *executing* the snippet. You're *compiling* the Trace class. How are you doing it? What are the packages of these two classes?

Comment: Yes @JBNizet, I apologies for mistake
I am not using any IDE,
I have defined Log.java and Trace.java in same directory and mentioned "package asgmnt;" in both the files.

Comment: So, what's the name of this directory, which commands are you executing, from which directory? Show us the tree of files/folders, and tell us what you're doing, precisely. Do that by editing your question.

Comment: Name of this directory is "asgmnt" and I have already compiled Log.java which was successful and I am getting above error, when I try to compile Trace.java using command javac "Trace.java"

Comment: have you imported Log.java in your Trace.java class?

Comment: If they are within same package, do I need to import ?

Comment: I highly suspect this is a duplicated of questions such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475491/javac-compiling-a-java-file-which-uses-other-classes-in-it), but will not flag it until we get all the information for the question.