# Trouble understanding/importing packages

Tags: java, package

I have 2 folders inside `myproject` directory.

The structure looks like this:

```
myproject
|
|-- graphs
|     |--------contains Graph1.java, Graph2.java
|
|
|-- gui
      |--------contains GUI things, like MainWindow.java
```

I'm trying to import the classes in `graphs` in `MainWindow.java`. Both `Graph1.java` and `Graph2.java` have `package graphs;` declared at the top of the files. In my `MainWindow.java`, I'm trying to import `Graph1.java` and `Graph2.java`.

When I type `import graphs.*` in `MainWindow.java` and try to create new instances of the classes to be imported, it gives me a compile error, saying it cannot find said package/symbol. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I try to compile with `javac MainWindow.java` inside the directory containing `MainWindow.java`, and it gives me these errors:

`error: package graphs does not exist`

`error: cannot find symbol` (for `Graph1`, `Graph2`)

Comment: Please post a [mcve], and show how you compile: if you use the commandline: post the commands you used to compile and where relative to these directories.

Comment: See this answer and if it helps. [Where to put packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759812/where-to-put-java-packages-i-want-to-import)

Answer (score 0):

the other classes are not in your class path, i.e. the compiler doesn't know they even exist, when you compile you have to specify the class path explicitly.

see: [javac : Compiling a .java file which uses other classes in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475491/javac-compiling-a-java-file-which-uses-other-classes-in-it)

that being said I would highly suggest using a proper IDE like eclipse,intellj, VScode and use a build tool like maven. it worth the effort as adding more and more classes and jars that you need will mean bigger class path to manage