# Cannot Compile/Run the Default Package File in Java

Tags: java, package

I'm doing the Algorithm homework of Princeton University, which asked us to finish 2 functions.

The question is, when I want to compile "PercolationStats.java" which needs the class "Percolation" in the same directory, It shows the error message:

> PercolationStats.java:14: error: cannot find symbol

I tried to find the solution of "how to import default package" on Stackoverflow and turned out the answer that **there's no need to import**. I'm wondering the reason and I don't wanna use import package method since the homework spec said that **both files should be in default package**.

I will put both file I'd like to compile & run down below. I hope there's someone can tell me the reason/solution why this happened.

```
public class Percolation {
    private boolean[] id;
    private int number;
    public WeightedQuickUnionUF a;
    private boolean flag;

    public Percolation(int var1) {
        if (var1 < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please input parameter larger than 0!");
        }
        else {
            this.number = var1;
            this.id = new boolean[this.number * this.number + 2];
            this.a = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(this.number * this.number + 2);

            for (int var2 = 0; var2 < this.number * this.number + 2; ++var2) {
                this.id[var2] = false;
            }

        }
    }
}


public class PercolationStats {

    private int trial_num;
    private double[] log;

    public PercolationStats(int var1, int var2) {
        if (var1 >= 1 && var2 >= 1) {
            Percolation pr = new Percolation(var1);
            trial_num = var2;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please make sure both input greater equal than 1!");
        }
    }
}
```

For readability, I only put the constructor of both class. And I
used following command to compile and run:

```bash
$  javac PercolationStats.java
$  java PercolationStats.java
```

The compile error happened in:

> Percolation pr = new Percolation(var1);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javac : Compiling a .java file which uses other classes in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475491/javac-compiling-a-java-file-which-uses-other-classes-in-it)

Comment: @Turamarth Thanks for your reply, I tried the command `javac Percolation.java PercolationStats.java` (same as `javac *.java`) and the code can be compiled successfully. However, when I try `java PercolationStats.java` to run, it still shows error `error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: `java PercolationStats.java` is for [single file source code execution](https://www.baeldung.com/java-single-file-source-code) which explicitly limits you to code from a single file (and doesn't require the earlier `javac` call). If you want to run the class you just compiled, you need to specify the **class name** and not the full **file name**. I.e. `java PercolationStats` (without the `.java`!).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks! I tried `javac Percolation.java PercolationStats.java` -> `java PercolationStats` and it still turned out that it couldn't find the Percolation class. Maybe I'll try to reset my java environment.

Comment: Do you have the `CLASSPATH` variable set? Try explicitly providing `-cp .` to both `javac` and `java`